# What are fragments in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#razor-templates what are fragments?

Comment: As I understand it fragments(renderfragments) are delegates ...

Comment: http://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fragment is a chunk or fragment of HtmL content, such as element tags and text, razor mark-up and components, executed in the form of a delegate (RenderFragment)

Here's a simple sample demonstrating this concept:

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<TestComponent>
    <p>Get Ready for a new era in Web development</p>
</TestComponent>
```

### TestComponent.razor

```
<div>@ChildContent</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    protected RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

The above sample describes a parent component named Index, and a nested or child component TestComponent. The content of the nested TestComponent is provided by the parent component, and it is passed to TestComponent in the form of a parameter of RenderFragment delegate. This delegate is invoked in the view portion of the component thus:

```
<div>@ChildContent</div>
```

And the html fragment is rendered within the div like this

```
<div><p>Get Ready for a new era in Web development</p></div>
```

Hope this helps...